# get_post_meta not working with variable as a post_id for dynamically get the postid

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, wp-mail, id

I would like to use the get_post_meta  to pull a value from a CPT dynamically and then send a email.

The problem is that the get_post_meta($post->ID,  ...  part of the code does not pull the email from the CPT metabox. If you replace the $post->ID,   with a post ID example "254" the entire function works perfectly.  Is there a way that I can have get_post_meta  use the post ID dynamically

```
    <?php
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Fire mail on post page and CPT
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  Add Hooks for Email 
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    add_action('new_to_publish', 'send_emails_on_new_event');
    add_action('post_updated', 'send_emails_on_new_event');

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  SET EMAIL FROM ADDRESS
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    function change_mail_from() {
        return "noreply@somedomain.co.za";
    }
        add_filter ("wp_mail_from", "change_mail_from");

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  SET EMAIL FROM NAME
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    function change_from_name() {
        return "Some Where";
    }
    add_filter ("wp_mail_from_name", "change_from_name");

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  SET EMAIL TYPE TO HTML
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    function wpse27856_set_content_type(){
        return "text/html";
    }
    add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type','wpse27856_set_content_type' );

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  Send emails on event publication
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    function send_emails_on_new_event($post_id)
    {
        $post                   =   get_post($post_id);
        $post_id                =   $post->ID;
        $post_type              =   'CPT name'; //post, page, attachment or         
    whatever other CPT you may have
        $author                 =   get_userdata($post->post_author);
        $author_id              =   $author->ID;
        $extra_email            =   get_post_meta($post->ID,     '_metabox_flied_from_CPT_with_extra_email', true);
        $admin_email            =   get_option('admin_email');
    $emails                 =   "$admin_email, $extra_email, $author->user_email"; //If you want to send to site administrator, use $emails = get_option('admin_email');
    $title                  =   wp_strip_all_tags(get_the_title($post->ID));
    $url                    =   get_permalink($post->ID);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  Email lay out
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////   
       ob_start(); ?>
        <html>
                <head>
                <title></title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <p>
                Hi 
            </p>
            <p>
                <?php echo $author->user_login ;?> has created a new entry maintenance system.
            </p>
            <p>
                Some Content
            </p>
        </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    $message = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    if(get_post_type($post_id) === $post_type)
    wp_mail($emails, "New/Updated Post. Ref number $title", $message);
}?>
```

Notes:

The funny thing is if you update a post all work well.

```
add_action('post_updated', 'send_emails_on_new_event');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `global $post;` on top of your code. But it depends on where the function is called.

Comment: require get_template_directory() . '/inc/function-send-email-if-maintenances-post.php'; in the functions.php

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. There is a function with an argument `$post_id`, but inside that function you retrieve the `$post->ID` again?

Comment: Thank will fix but $post_id = $post->ID so does not matter with one you use

Comment: If you call this function, you already have the post's id, don't you? So why do you have to search for it again inside the function? Doesn't make the least bit of sense to me...

Comment: Even if I change the $post->ID  to $post_id the script still does not work.

Comment: That's not the point. The point is how you use this function. It takes `$post_id` as an argument, so logically the post ID should be determined *before* you call this function, not inside of it. Or am I missing something?